# Permanently retrieving a HttpStatusException with status 500 using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup, web-crawler

I want to use Jsoup to access some data of a website located on a network server. Everytime I try to connect via a valid URL I'm retrieving a HttpStatusException with the following error:

`Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=500, URL=http://sv.thisismydomain.de/path/xyz.jsp` (I've changed the URL)

This is my attempt:

```
System.out.println(Jsoup.connect(urlBase + urlLoginForm).userAgent(userAgent).timeout(10000).get().html());
```

I'm sure that this is the correct URL. The URL works fine if I copy it out of the StackTrace into my browser - so this can't be the problem.

This is the user agent I'm using:

```
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) " +
                   "Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36";
```

Do you have any ideas? This drives me crazy!

Comment: urlBase + urlLoginForm, what are the value of urlBase and urlLoginForm??

Comment: String urlBase = "ht tp:/ /sv.thisismydomain.de/path/ " String urlLoginForm = "xyz.jsp"; // (added spaces because the editor recognizes the value as a hyperlink)

Answer (score 2):

Status 500 is a permanant error. It means the server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.No way around it other than handlin it in server. Since you are saying the url is working perfectly there can we certain possibilites that we could re-check. These may not exactly be a reason of 505.

1) When you say `urlBase + urlLoginForm` there could be chance to miss a `\`. Say you have `urlBase = http://sv.thisismydomain.de/path` and `urlLoginForm = xyz.jsp` when you construct it could be `http://sv.thisismydomain.de/pathxyz.jsp` instead of `http://sv.thisismydomain.de/path/xyz.jsp`
If `urlLoginForm` is a parameter list you should re-check how it is constructed.
**This should ideally return a 404 but since the domain part is correct chances are there it can explicitly fail with a 505.

2) The site you are trying to might be checking the source of the request. So you could rely on the `referrer` method of Jsoup in this case.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urlBase + urlLoginForm).referrer(urlBase + urlLoginForm).userAgent(userAgent).timeout(10000).get();
```

** ideally this should return a Forbidden 403 error or access denied.

3) Make sure get method is supported. try using post. Again this should return a Method 303, but just in case.. ;)

4) The URL doesn't show any issue. Since its behind a proxy you could try setting proxy properties before invoking jsoup.connect(). But again this should result in time out and not 505.

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "<your host ip>");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "<proxy port>");
```

Sorry to give all these suggestion which are unrelated to 505. Since I don't have access to your URL this is the best I could suggest. :)

Comment: The URL is correct. I've copied it out of the StackTrace into the browsers address bar - works perfectly. Thanks for the advice but it does not work as well. I've also tried the post()-method - still getting the same exception. Maybe it's nice to know that the page I want to access is a HTML frame.

Comment: Iframes shouldnt be a problem. Just check the syntax of the html of that url. Basically you would either have an <iframe> inside a body tag, or <frame> tags inside a frameset and no body tag at all. Jsoup will parse it even if its wrong but might reject the frame tags. Can you share the actual url if possible. Or try connecting without the user-agent.

Comment: It's a frame inside a frameset. I've used the correct URL of the frame. I've tried the connection without setting the user-agent but it doesn't work either. I'm sorry but I can't share the the URL, because the website is located on a internal server. But here is a pattern with changed letters: http://sv-ms-03a.ab.abcd.de/AbcDefghi/abcd/abc.jsp

Comment: Url is fine. Since its internal you might have access to the server right? Check what cases return 505 or server logs etc. Or try opening that connection via a java.net.URL. jsoup might be using this but still try it simple. Or before that try using proxy setting. Updated in answer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I already tried it with proxy settings and they seem fine since I was able to connect to every other site on the web. Unfortunately I don't have access to that server (it's not the smallest company and I'm just a programmer - not an administrator). And it's an Error 500 not 505 but I think that's not even better. Thanks for all these suggestions so far!